# What does mean 'c.X' date format in history ? (with X a number)

Tags: date

English is not my native language and I didn't found the answer on the net. I read on different places "he died c.405", what does mean this 'c.' notation?
Is it about centuries? (example here on Wikipedia: [Uí Néill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U%C3%AD_N%C3%A9ill))

Comment: The 'c.' stands for circa, which means _approximately_ (i.e. in your example the year of death isn't conclusively proved.)

Comment: Ok so it's 405 A.D in this case ? (I guess it is if B.C is not mentioned ?)

Comment: Without any other information, I'd assume A.D./C.E.

Comment: You may find that info spelled out here: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/circa